# Excel VBA code to select cells that contain a certain text string in one workbook, and then copy and paste these cells into a new workbook

Tags: vba, excel, select, find

I have a large set of data contained within single column in an Excel spreadsheet. I have been trying to work out a way of automating a method to select certain data from this column in one workbook, and paste it into a column in a new workbook.

For example, I have a list of names in the column. I wanted to select any cells that contain the text "First name:", and then copy and paste these cells into a column in a different workbook.

I can do this manually using the 'Find All' tool within Excel, selecting the cells using 'Find what:', and then using Ctrl+A to select all the items found, then closing the 'Find All' tool, and using Ctrl+C to copy all the cells, moving on to the next workbook, and then using Ctrl+V to paste these cells. However, I need to do this process quite a large number of times, and unfortunately the Macro recorder does not record any queries / processes performed in the 'Find All' tool.

I'm assuming that I need some VBA code, but have been unable to find anything suitable on the web / forums.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a sample to get you started:

```
Sub Luxation()
    Dim K As Long, r As Range, v As Variant
    K = 1
    Dim w1 As Workbook, w2 As Workbook
    Set w1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set w2 = Workbooks.Add
    w1.Activate
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        v = r.Value
        If InStr(v, "First name") > 0 Then
            r.Copy w2.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(K, 1)
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

The code opens a fresh workbook, goes back to the original workbook, runs down column **A** , and then copies the relevant cells to the fresh workbook.

**EDIT#1**

Here is the new macro:

```
Sub Luxation2()
    Dim K As Long, r As Range, v As Variant
    K = 1
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Set w1 = Sheets("raw data")
    Set w2 = Sheets("data manipulation")
    w1.Activate
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        v = r.Value
        If InStr(v, "First name") > 0 Then
            r.Copy w2.Cells(K, 1)
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant, that seems to work. Thanks ever so much for that. However, I think I used some incorrect terminology in my question. I was actually trying to do the selection from a single workbook, from a tab entitled 'raw data', and pasting into a tab entitled 'data manipulation'. Can I use the same code above to select from one tab and paste into the next tab, as I'm not sure what requires modification? Thanks again for your help, very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks again. Is it easy to modify this code to copy from one tab to another, in the same workbook (see comment above)? Sorry, I'm very new to coding, and have not been able to work it out from reading other forum posts. Thanks

Comment: Super. Are you able to point me in the right direction please? Thanks in advance.